# Not getting expected simplification of trigonometric expressions

Tags: trigonometry

I have two trigonometric expressions. I would like to eliminate the fraction from my 2nd expression.

```
A = (-Cos[ψ2] Sin[η2] Sin[θ2] + Cos[η2] Sin[ψ2]) 

B = (-D + d Cos[η2] Cos[θ2] Cos[ϕ2] + 1/2 l Cos[θ2] Sin[η2] + Q2 Sin[θ2] - d Sin[θ2] Sin[ϕ2] + (Q1 Cos[θ1] Cos[θ2] Sin[η2] (Cos[η2] Cos[θ2] Cos[ϕ2] - Sin[θ2] Sin[ϕ2])) / (Cos[ψ2] Sin[η2] Sin[θ2] - Cos[η2] Sin[ψ2]))
```

I tried `Simplify` and `FullSimplify` to suppress the denominator but the denominator in the expression `B` (equal to `A`) is not suppressed.

```
Simplify[A*B]
```

Please help me to force Mathematica to make the simplifications so as to eliminate the denominator of the expression `B` which is equal to `A` ?

Comment: Try `Simplify@Expand[A*B]`

Comment: Or `Cancel[A*B]`.

Answer (score 1):

First let me explain what is going on.

```
 A // FullForm
```

> ```
> Plus[Times[-1, Cos[ψ2], Sin[η2], Sin[θ2]], Times[Cos[η2], Sin[ψ2]]]
> ```

However, what you consider the denominator of the fractional part of `b` is

```
(Cos[ψ2] Sin[η2] Sin[θ2] - Cos[η2] Sin[ψ2]) // FullForm
```

> Plus[Times[Cos[ψ2], Sin[η2], Sin[θ2]], Times[-1, Cos[η2], Sin[ψ2]]]

So the two forms don't look the same to Mathematica and don't get cancelled.

There are many ways to solve the problem. One has already been suggested in a comment. Here is another.

```
AA = -1 A;
Simplify[AA B]
```

[image: trig_expression]